# Magento 2: Change Product status OUT OF STOCK Programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, stock, out-of-stock

I need to change product as `out of stock` without changing its Quantity. I mean if a product having quantity `5`, It will be same but product would be changed to `OUT OF STOCK`. Is it possible in magento?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
) {
    $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    $this->_product = $product;
}
```

And after

```
$product=$this->_product->load($productId); //load product which you want to update stock
$stockItem=$this->_stockRegistry->getStockItem($item['product_id']); // load stock of that product
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock',0);       
$stockItem->save();
$product->save();
```